# Table margins and paddings

Tags: tables, spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables)

How do I adjust the padding in a table, meaning the distance between cell content and cell border? And how do I allow normal text flow so line breaks are added automatically, so the table doesn't stretch over the margin?

These margin/padding problems are illustrated in the figure:

[image: Table example]

Comment: There are many things that one can do. To name a few: use `arraystretch` to adjust spacing between rows, `@{}` construct to change column spacing and delimiters, `p`-columns to make column fixed width. If you can provide an example working code, it will be easier to help.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31672/column-padding-in-tables